# Read data from Kafka and print to console with Spark Structured Sreaming in Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have **kafka_2.13-2.7.0** in Ubuntu 20.04. I run kafka server and zookeeper then create a topic and send a text file in it via `nc -lk 9999`. The topic is full of data. Also, I have **spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7** on my system. In fact, I want to use the kafka topic as a source for Spark Structured Streaming with python. My code is like this:

```py
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("APP") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "sparktest") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
df.printSchema()
```

I run the above code via **spark-submit** with this command:

```
./spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1 /home/spark/PycharmProjects/testSparkStream/KafkaToSpark.py
```

The code run without any exception and I receive this output as it is in Spark site:

```
   root
    |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
    |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
    |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
    |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
    |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
    |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

My question is that the kafka topic is full of data;but there is no any data as a result of running the code in output. Would you please guide me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code as is will not print out any data but only provide you the schema once.

You can follow the instructions given in the general [Structured Streaming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) and the [Structured Streaming + Kafka integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) to see how to print out data to the console. Remember that reading data in Spark is a lazy operation and nothing is done without an action (typically a `writeStream` operation).

If you complement the code as below you should see the selected data (key and value) printed out to the console:

```py
spark = SparkSession \
          .builder \
          .appName("APP") \
          .getOrCreate()

df = spark\
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
      .option("subscribe", "sparktest") \
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
      .load()
      

query = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/HDFS/dir") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```